# Why does Node lose the session in production but not in development?

Tags: node.js, cookies, express-session

I have a Node/Express site hosted at Hetzner on a Debian Linux with Nginx/pm2.

My server.ts has these session/cookie settings:

```
import * as model from './model.js';
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import * as config from './config.js';
import { INewBook } from './interfaces.js';
import session from 'express-session';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';

declare module 'express-session' {
    export interface SessionData {
        user: { [key: string]: any };
    }
}

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({
    origin: config.FRONTEND_URL,
    methods: ['POST', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'PUT', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD'],
    credentials: true
}));
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
    session({
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        secret: config.SESSION_SECRET,
        cookie: {
            httpOnly: true,
            sameSite: config.NODE_ENVIRONMENT === 'production' ? 'none' : 'lax',
            secure: config.NODE_ENVIRONMENT === 'production'
        }
    })
);

app.all('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://et-mern-crud-site.tanguay.eu");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next();
});
```

When I output my session during login, it shows that e.g. req.session.user = 'admin' but when the browser comes back to check the current user, the session is lost.

[image]

This code works locally in development but not in production.

What do I need to change so that Node remembers my session in production?

Answer (score 0):

I finally came upon the answer.

Instead of:

```
sameSite: 'none',
secure: true
```

I needed:

```
sameSite: 'lax',
secure: false
```

That means that these settings are the same locally as in production at Hetzner. It used to be the opposite at Heroku, but for some reason this is not the case on my Debian machine at Hetzner.